# Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get value from the user in dart. but this error occurs during the run time and the program doesn't give proper results. can anyone help me with this?

[Watch the screenshot of the code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgNwa.png)

**I want a proper solution to this error.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Click on the link to get full code.